# problem with fetch in componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs

my list of users is undefined when i try to console.log it.
Maybe i didn't get something ?

I'd like to get my list of users from my api who works (tested with postman) and put it into the console next i'd like to map my users to show it on the app

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component did mount");
    fetch("/user/list")
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(users => 
      this.setState({users}, () => 
      console.log("list of users => " + users)));
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="form">
      <ul>
        {this.state.users.map((user) =>
          <li key="user._id">{ user.name }</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
} export default Test;
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `res.json()` rather than returning `res.json()` from the first `then` on your fetch call

I've found this pattern to be helpful:

```
fetch(url)
   .then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject())
```

As your code is now, `users` (the parameter in the second `then` would be undefined, because you are not returning anything from the first `then`

Comment: Hello, thanks. But I still have my undefined (I corrected the code above)

Comment: sorry i've made a mistake, it works but i got [object Object] now

Comment: @jim2k your log statement is appending an array of objects to a string, try `console.log('users => ', users);`

Comment: thank you man ! i didn't even know that it was possible to get problems like this one ! ;)
Last question if you don't mind, i modify the render to display this.state.users via a map, but it says that "this.state.users.map" isn't a function and it doesn't work. Any idea ? after I leave you alone I promise !

Answer (score 1):

you have to return the `res.json()` to use it in the next `.then()`

```
.then(res => {
    res.json();
})
```

should be

```
.then(res => 
    res.json();
)
```

Or

```
.then(res => {
    return res.json();
})
```

https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: ok I got it. But even if I return res.json() i still have my undefined ! (I modify the code)

Comment: sorry i've made a mistake, it works but i got [object Object] now

Comment: yeah because `console.log` will try to `stringify` the `users`, use a comma `,` instead of `+` , try `console.log("list of users => " , users)));`

Comment: omg thank you, i would have never found this by myself, such a detail haha !
I'm new in this sorry. Last question if you don't mind, i modify the render to display this.state.users via a map, but it says that "this.state.users.map" isn't a function and it doesn't work. Any idea ? after I leave you alone I promise !

Comment: are you sure the `users` list is an array ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing your res into res.json() and returning the results into your state.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component did mount");
    fetch("/user/list")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(users => 
      this.setState(users, 
        () => {
            console.log("list of users => " + users)
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks !
i corrected this but i got an other problem.  i modify the render to display this.state.users via a map, but it says that "this.state.users.map" isn't a function and it doesn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: console.log(typeof this.state.users) should output Array. If it does not, what you are returning from your fetch needs to be put into an array via .push() or handled better on the server side to do so before sending.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Jasper response help me so much!

I found that fetch with GET method does not work if we pass any request body.

the full example is here
https://github.com/alexunjm/todo-list-react

```
const buildRequestOptions = ({
  method = "GET",
  raw = null, // I had my error here!, with GET raw need to be null
  customHeaders = {name: 'value'},
}) => {
  var myHeaders = buildHeaders(customHeaders);

  var requestOptions = {
    method,
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw,
    redirect: "follow",
  };

  return requestOptions;
};

const listTasks = () => {
  const url = `${uriBase}/task/sample`;
  const requestOptions = buildRequestOptions({
    customHeaders: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
  return fetch(url, requestOptions);
}

const asyncFn = ({
  promiseToWait,
  pendingFn,
  successFn,
  errorFn,
}) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(pendingFn());
    promiseToWait
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        }
        // handled from server status 422 and 401
        if (res.status === 422) {
          // error message on body from server
          return res.json();
        }
        if (res.status === 401) {
          // custom error message hardcoded
          return {errors: {action: 'no authorized'}}
        }
        console.log("http response no controlled", res);
        return Promise.reject();
      })
      .then((body) => {
        if (body.errors) {
          const errors = Object.keys(body.errors).map(
            (key) => key + " " + body.errors[key]
          );
          dispatch(errorFn(errors.join("; ")));
        } else {
          dispatch(successFn(body));
        }
        return body;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error", error);
        dispatch(errorFn("Unavailable server connection"));
      });
  };
};

const queryTasks = () => {
  return asyncFn({
    promiseToWait: listTasks(),
    pendingFn: apiPending,
    successFn: apiSuccessList,
    errorFn: apiError,
  });
}
```